# Highlight selected word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to implement both highlight and un-highlight selected text in a textarea. Could please help me to implement this one. I tried following code for highlight and un-highlight

```
$('.highlight').click(function(){
    var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();

    var span= document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(span);
});

$('.remove_highlight').click(function(){
    var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(span);
});
```

here, .highlight and .remove_highlight are separate buttons, thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly do you want? Because I tried this code and is working as expected. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ozvhchhc/)

Comment: sorry for inconvenience it doesn't support on edge and it is not a standard way to do the expected task because it adds so much of span inside another span when we do lot of highlight and unhighlight in same word.

Comment: @Gugan Have a look at this article, there's a plugin for textarea elements too: https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/